# Python : Passing arguments during instantiation

Tags: python

I have a class called "data-packet" shown below. I am trying to instantiate it so that I can use the values returned by the methods `getAcc` and `getRot`. I have also included the code that is creating an instance of the data_packet class in "main"
I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
mydata = data_packet()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

My assumption is that the instance is passing `mydata` to the argument called self, but nothing is being passed to l. If I am correct, how can I solve this error?

```
class data_packet (object):
    def __init__(self, l):

        self.data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        self.type = ord(l[2])

        if self.type == 0:   # accel

            self.data[0] = four_bytes(l[3],l[4],l[5],l[6]) * 1.0 / (1<<16)
            self.data[1] = four_bytes(l[7],l[8],l[9],l[10]) * 1.0 / (1<<16)
            self.data[2] = four_bytes(l[11],l[12],l[13],l[14]) * 1.0 /(1<<16)

        elif self.type == 6:   # heading
            self.data[0] = four_bytes(l[3],l[4],l[5],l[6]) * 1.0 / (1<<16)

        else:   # unsupported
            pass


    def display(self):    
        if self.type == 0:
            print 'accel: %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f' % \
                     (self.data[0], self.data[1], self.data[2])

        elif self.type == 6:
            print 'heading: %7.4f' % self.data[0]

        else:
            print 'what?'

    def getAcc(self):
        while self.type == 0:

            .....dosomethings....

        return accelData

    def getRot(self):
        while self.type == 5:

        ..... dosomethings....

        return rotData


def main():
    mydata = data_packet()
    mydata.getAcc()
    mydata.getRot()
    print "********* : ", mydata.getAcc()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: You say the code is below, but you didnt actually put any of the code. That would help us a lot

Comment: My apologies... I have been struggling to post the code. Check the edited version of the question. Thanks

Comment: Er, you solve this by passing the value of `l` in the instantiation. Why is that confusing?

Comment: And `l` being an iterable.

Comment: @a_bhi_9 : actually it has to be subscriptable, not iterable...

Comment: When I pass "l" as the argument as follows mydata = data_packet(l), I get this NameError: global name 'l' is not defined

Comment: "When I pass "l" as the argument as follows mydata = data_packet(l), I get this NameError: global name 'l' is not defined" - well, **what did you want the value of `l` to be**, and where did you want it to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` in object methods is a reference to the instantiated object. When calling a method via dot notation, e.g. `mydata.getAcc()`, the object is automatically passed on as the first parameter. A more explicit way of achieving the same is calling the method via the class: `data_package.getAcc(mydata)`.

`__init__` is called automatically at object instantiation, but otherwise it works the same. Writing `data_package()` can be imagined as  `data_package.__init(new_object)`.
However, in your class definition, you defined a second parameter `l` for `__init`. Your object instantiation should be `data_package(l)`, that way, `l` is passed over to `__init__` as its second parameter. i.e. `data_package.__init(new_object, l)`.

Comment: When I pass "l" as the argument as follows mydata = data_packet(l), I get this NameError: global name 'l' is not defined

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback

Comment: You have to define `l` before passing it to your class instantiation. Most probably `l` is a list...

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can do that given the above code??

Comment: well, where is the data coming from that you want to put into `four_bytes()`?

Comment: This is really application dependent, it looks like `l` is a list with at least 15 elements. Since you didn't post the code of your `four_bytes` function it's really difficult to say how the list should be built.

Comment: def four_bytes(d1, d2, d3, d4):

    d = ord(d1)*(1<<24) + ord(d2)*(1<<16) + ord(d3)*(1<<8) + ord(d4)

    if d > 2147483648:
        d-= 4294967296

    return d

Comment: The data is being received from the MPU9150

Comment: Please understand that we have no idea what MPU9150 is. You'll have to  figure out yourself what part of the incoming data should be used to create your object. As was said, it will probably be a list or tuple, as it has to allow accessing items via index.

Comment: An MPU9150 is an electronic device that sends accelerometer, gyroscope and other data to a PC

Comment: Okay. You still have to figure out yourself what structure that data has when it arrives in Python. If some of it is a list/tuple of at least 15 bytes, that's probably what you want to be passing on.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems pretty obvious from both the code and the traceback: your `data_packet` class takes a required argument `l` (that is "L" lower-case - an identifier one should never use...) - obviously a `list` FWIW - that you don't pass.

NB:`self` is the current instance and is automagically passed in.

Comment: When I pass "l" as the argument as follows mydata = data_packet(l), I get this NameError: global name 'l' is not defined

Comment: l is not defined because you have probably not initialized it before creating the data_packet object. also you do not have to name it l when you pass it to your object i.e mydata = data_packet([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,....])